# 24 hour format for Python timestamp

Tags: python, datetime, time, timestamp

Currently I'm creating timestamps with the Python time module. I created a string using this command

```py
timestamp = time.strftime('%l:%M:%S')
```

However, this prints the format in a 12-hour format. Is there a way I can do this in a 24-hour format so it would show up as `20:52:53` instead of `8:52:53`?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try

```
timestamp = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Check out this link for info on Python time module

https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime

Answer (score 0):

If you're located in a locale that uses the 24-hour format, you can also use `'%X'`.

```py
import datetime
time = datetime.time(23, 12, 36)
timestamp = time.strftime('%X')            # '23:12:36'

dt = datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 5, 23, 12, 36)
dt.strftime('%X')                          # '23:12:36'
```

N.B. There's a typo in the question. To show time in 12h format, the format should be `'%I:%M:%S'` (`I` not `l`). In addition, to show AM or PM, use `'%I:%M:%S %p'`.

For a full list of possible formats, see https://strftime.org/.